# Customize yocto's build configuration output at start

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Is it possible to customize the `Build Configuration` dump which is printed at the very beginning of each bitbake call? I'm using different flags and overrides to fine tune things like development/testing/deployment mode and I would to have these printed to the terminal to make sure I didn't miss stetting any important flags.
Is that possible? If yes, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

The output of the Build Configuration is configured by the variable `BUILDCFG_VARS` defined in the [bitbake.conf](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/conf/bitbake.conf#n707) file.

You can i.e. append values to it in your `local.conf`. I think the output is evaluated early, so it might not use the values that would be used in a particular recipe.